# what is the concatenation operation,"||", in the formulation of GNN

Tags: graph-theory

There is a formulation in EGNN.

Each edge feature $\mathbf{e}_{i j}=\left\{e_{i j d}\right\}_{d=1}^{2} \in[0,1]^{2}$ is a 2-dimensional vector representing the (normalized) strengths
of the intra- and inter-class relations of the two connected
nodes. This allows to separately exploit the intra-cluster
similarity and the inter-cluster dissimilairity.

Edge features are initialized by edge labels as follows:
$$
\mathbf{e}_{i j}^{0}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}{[1 || 0],} & {\text { if } y_{i j}=1 \text { and } i, j \leq N \times K} \\ {[0| | 1],} & {\text { if } y_{i j}=0 \text { and } i, j \leq N \times K} \\ {[0.5| | 0.5],} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.
$$
where || is the concatenation operation.

It is about edge features. But I don't know the meaning of the concatenation operation. I don't know the '||' in this formulation. Also, It is hard to search it on google. So I ask help to the community.

Comment: “Concatenation” means that you have two (or more) vectors and that you just merge them into one vector, the entries if which are the entries of all your original vectors.

Comment: So, how to explain $[0.5| | 0.5]$?

Comment: This seems probably a poor notation for $[0.5;0.5]$?

Comment: Thank you for your warm explain. But I can not convince myself.

Comment: Maybe you are right. It's that simple.